# Unable to intercept method call via Byte Buddy agent

Tags: byte-buddy

I want to intercept a method call via byte buddy to do some logging.  I already have compile-time byte code enhancement working, but am not having luck with setting up the same thing, but with an agent:

Interceptor:

```
public class LogInterceptor {
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(
      @Origin Method method,
      @SuperCall Callable<?> callable) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("intercepting: {}", method);
    System.out.println("intercepting: " + method);
    return callable.call();
  }
}
```

Agent:

```
void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    final Method method = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString");

    ElementMatcher.Junction<MethodDescription> executeMethodDecription = ElementMatchers.isMethod()
              .and(ElementMatchers.named(method.getName()))
              .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAbstract()))
              .and(ElementMatchers.is(method));

    final AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION);
agentBuilder.type(ElementMatchers.is(method.getDeclaringClass()))
        .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module, other) ->
          builder.method(executeMethodDecription).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogInterceptor.class))).installOn(instrumentation);
      }
```

Cmdline:

```
java -javaagent:log-agent-shaded.jar -jar application.jar > .log 2>&1
```

When running the cmdline as show above, I have an additional log statement printing a warning that it is installing on the class and method I expect.  However, at runtime, I don't see the log statement I am expecting.

In my plugin, I have essentially this:

```
builder.method(ElementMatchers.is(methodDescription)).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogInterceptor.class));
```

I am able to intercept the method if used at compile-time, but I also want to be able to do the same at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are loading the class from your agent. In this case, you'd need to activate retransformation. Better though if you avoid the premature loading altogether and obly match by using strings.

Comment: Ah, I updated my example above to activate retransformation, but it still does not appear to be working as expected.  Is there anything else I need to do?  Also, if I have multiple classes I want to intercept, I can use the same agentBuilder, correct?  I don't need a new instance for each instance I want to intercept?

Comment: You can instrument multiple classes. Have you tried registering a logging listener? Possibly, there is an exception that you miss.